# Excel formula- stop recalculating formula past a set date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Stop recalculating formula past a set date?
I have a summary file that links to each of my project files, respectively. I update the project files weekly. My summary file is set up with column A-C being my project info, Row 2 is my dates, and columns D and beyond are set dates- weekly.  (Photo below for reference)

How can I set this summary file up so that:

IF the date in Row 2 on the summary file matches the date on the project file, it will update my numbers.

But if the project file is updated, that summary file column does not update- it keeps its value and the next column with the matching date updates to the current info.

Basically I want to freeze, archive, or deactivate the formula once that date has passed so I can track the numbers across a quarter.

[image: Excel summary file example]

Comment: Formula are live, best practice would be to use vba in worksheet events.  Or manually copy paste just the values at the end of each time period.

Comment: The other way is to setup your datasheet to record transactional data, then your summary sheet would use formulas to pull from that transactional data using date ranges. When you are beyond the date range that particular summary becomes "set"